# Instrument for the Art of fugue

Tags: fugue

Do you have references about the question of the instrumentation of the Art of fugue of Bach?

What do you think about the interpretation on piano forte?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Welcome! Please read about [the topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to avoid subjective questions and answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). There are two problems with this question right now, a request for external resources rather than asking for an answer right here, and a prompt for open-ended discussion and sharing opinions. There are definitely objective things to be said about instrumentation and The Art of the Fugue, though. I’m voting to close, but I invite you to edit to ask a more specific question.

Comment: perhaps a good question might be “what instrumentation did Bach intend, and how would he feel about these fugues being performed on other instruments?“ Spoiler, even for a composer who was  already very flexible about adapting for other instruments, this piece is even more “instrument-agnostic“ than most.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions asking for references and opinions are not covered here. However, the chat room is an excellent place for this. Anyone with a reputation higher than 20 may post there.

Comment: My professor told me that virtually nothing is known about the instrumentation of the _Kunst der Fuge_ . It might have been written for organ or harpsichord, but she said it could even be a reduction score of a composition for string ensemble

Comment: OK, thanks for your comments.

Comment: Three things I  know - 1) I have a pretty good vinyl recording, where it is performed by a string ensemble, 2) Bach wrote a lot of stuff on a clavichord 3) Bach wrote this piece as a study of fugue composing